# Data Model in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When using `Mobile Hub` (AWS), building a `DynamoDB` table. There is at some point the option to download the Data  Model for the table. But we do not see this option (AFAIK) if we do not use Mobile Hub. So the question is: *Is there a way to get the  Data  Model for the table, when not using Mobile Hub?*

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, DynamoDB doesn't have a full data model like RDBMS. However, it does have the hash key, partition key (if defined) and all the index details.

You can get this information using [Describe table API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html). The API will give the output in JSON format. Kindly look at the link for more information.

Please note that all the non-key attributes are not included in the data model. This is the basic concept in NoSQL database and this is the flexibility of NoSQL database when compared to RDBMS.

- The item structure (non-key attributes) need not be defined while
  creating the table. In fact, DynamoDB doesn't allow to define the
  non-key attributes while creating the table
- The non-key attributes in one item need not be same in the another
  item

Comment: OK. I'll start to use awscli then, so I can look into this describe table. Thanks for the tip.